# Do QuantLib 1.1 + SWIG + Ruby 1.9 work on Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, quantlib, quantlib-swig

For starters I would like to find out whether the latest version of QuantLib 1.1 is working with its Ruby bindings via SWIG with Ruby 1.9 on a Mac.
I installed QuantLib and QuantLib-SWIG along with Boost and SWIG itself via Homebrew but I get an error while executing QuantLib-SWIG's Ruby installer.
I just wouldn't want to waste time if QuantLib doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.